# How to Connect to Remote DataSource from SAP WebIDE Personal Edition

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am trying to call the OData Service from SAP WebIDE local/personal edition. I want to define the Datasource in manifest.JSON file and then create the model with the same data source. As mentioned in SAPUI5 Walkthrough :

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html

They are creating the destination in HANA trial account -> Destination.

In my case, there is not HANA Trial account. Where I can create the destination so that my manifest.json file can read this destination and connect to data source.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Web IDE personal edition destination should be created under the following path:

```
C:\SAPWebIDE\eclipse\config_master\service.destinations\destinations
```

inside the destinations folder you need to create one file per destination. The file must be **without extension** usually the name of the file should be the name of the system that you want to connect to e.g. (Q7D etc.)

The file should have the following structure (taken from Web IDE docs):

```
Description=<mysystem> description
Type=HTTP
TrustAll=true
Authentication=NoAuthentication
Name=<mysystem>
ProxyType=Internet
URL=https\://<host>\:<port>
WebIDEUsage=<add a value according to the table below>
WebIDESystem=<mysystem>
WebIDEEnabled=true
sap-client=<SAP client number for ABAP systems only. Delete this line if you are not using an ABAP system.>
```

You can find more details about the destination file in [here](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?2cf47f37e34c428c97a51057733c0394.html)

After you create the new destination open Web IDE and create a new project based on template (e.g. master/detail) in the select service wizard step select the system and then generate a new app. The generated app will contain all the code that you need (manifest, datasources, views , controllers etc.) the only thing that left is just to run it :)

Good Luck!