# Connecting to Remote Systems

Tags: sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-connector

I'm having some troubles when I configure my archive (I'm using SAP Web IDE Personal Edition) and try to connect with my server.

This is my configuration:

```
Description=Servidor Fiori - FSD
Type=HTTPS
TrustAll=true                                                                   
Authentication=BasicAuthentication
Name=vm-kfmfiori
User=namari
Password=qwerty.30
WebIDEUsage=odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap
URL=https\://lookthepicture:port
ProxyType=Internet                                                  
WebIDESystem=FSD
WebIDEEnabled=true
sap-client=100
```

I take my info from this URL service:

[image]

The `Name` from here:

[image]

And `WebIDESystem` from here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? When I create my template, I can't see my connection :C

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036998/how-to-connect-to-remote-datasource-from-sap-webide-personal-edition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Connect to Remote DataSource from SAP WebIDE Personal Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036998/how-to-connect-to-remote-datasource-from-sap-webide-personal-edition)